# How Do I Check the Status of My Application or Registration?

Tags: patent-applications

How Do I Check the Status of My Application or Registration & get the summary description like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the google patents summary, so the only way to get that summary is to enter the application number at google (patents.google.com).

If the application is not public yet, you can find information on it through your private PAIR access from the USPTO, but you won't get a summary like the one you posted.

Answer (score 0):

not sure this is what you are looking for or mean but...

http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair

or there is a private version if you filed the patent. Talk to the USPTO if you need access and don't have it or consult your patent attorney.